# Test if array contains specific substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to test if an array contains a specific substring, but I can only get a match if the `substring = array value`

This is my test code:

```js
var test = ["something", "my-name", "name-test"];
if (test.includes('name')) {
  console.log(test);
}
```

I've also tried with `indexOf('navn') !== -1` and jQuery inArray.

However, no matter what I try, it only works if I my `substring == array value`, but I need **'name'** to be **'true'** when array value is e.g. 'my-name' or 'name-test'.

It seems so simple, yet I can't get it to work.

Comment: `test.some(str => str.includes('name'))`

Comment: @ChrisG works perfect. Thanks :-) Please provide an answer so I can credit you

Comment: Glad it works, however I'm not here for cheap points grabbing so won't post an answer. This a dupe anyway :)